# Creating a Christmas Tree - Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods

```
 public static void printStars(int num){
    for (int x = 0; x< num; x++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
public static void printSpaces(int spaces){
    for (int y = 1; y<= spaces ; y++){
        System.out.print("0");
    }
}
public static void leftLeaningTriangle(int num){
    for (int m = 1; m<=num; m++){
        printStars(m);
    }
}
public static void rightLeaningTriangle (int tri){
    for (int n =1; n<=tri;n++){
        printSpaces(tri-n);
        printStars(n);
    }
}
public static void christmasTree(int height){
    for (int i = 1; i<=height; i++){
        int z = height-i;
        printSpaces(z);
        height++;
        printStars(i++);
    }
```

Hi, Can someone please help me understand why the christmas tree pattern would have 1 star at the top instead of 2 with the code above? with printStars(i++) wouldn't it be printStars(2)?
I do have a main method, it just insn't shown here.

Comment: Minus one on the vote and a single close. You have to love the Java tag!

Comment: Please explain in English what you think `i++` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `printStars(i++)`, the initial value, not the incremented value of `i` is passed to the function.

`i` is only increased once the function has ran: your code is equivalent to

```
printStars(i);
i = i + 1;
```

Comment: @OliveGalia: It's a common thing across all the C-type languages. You'll get used to it in time.

Comment: Just to clarify, this would mean - printStars(i++) would increase i by 1 once it is executed and the the for loop i++ iteration happens after? Increasing h by 1  and increasing i by 2, before the loop starts again? Is that right?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`i++` uses the post-increment operator, which first returns the original value of the variable and then increments it by 1.

Answer (score 0):

try `++i`
`i++` takes the value of i then increment it so the function well take 1
by using `++i` i will increase 1 then it well be passed the function